# Как с помощью Go прочесть метаданные аудио файла?

Tags: golang, аудио, metadata

Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, есть ли вообще возможность через Golang узнать метаданные аудиофайла? Если нельзя именно через Golang, то через что можно?

Просто мне нужно узнать общее время аудиофайла(duration) получив его на сервер Golang и записать его в БД. Но для этого мне нужно прочитать мета-данные данного аудиофайла при получении. Если есть другие способы для вычисления общего времени аудиофайла, то буду рад услышать их.

Comment: Думаю это можно сделать используя [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281655/how-to-find-the-length-of-mp3-file-in-golang) на англоязычном SO.

Answer (score 0):

В общем для работы с Метаданными аудиофайла можно использовать библиотеку TagLib. И для golang есть отдельная библиотека написанная на golang, которая выполняет нужные функции библиотеки TagLib(используя эту библиотеку).